# Why does gcd(m,N) have to be 1 in RSA?

Tags: rsa

In the RSA algorithm, if an attacker wants to get $d$, the attacker does this simply by encrypting random messages $m < N$.

If the attacker ﬁnds a message $m_1$ that the attacker can not encrypt since $\gcd(N ,m_1) \neq 1$, does this help the attacker in any way in any way?

I don't know why the $\gcd(m,N)$ has to be $1$. What happens if $\gcd(m,N) \neq 1$?

Comment: Dupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/does-rsa-work-for-any-message-m and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25648/how-do-we-guarantee-plaintext-is-coprime-in-rsa

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What happens if $\gcd(m,N) \neq 1$?

Actually, RSA works just fine; we have $((m^e)^d) \equiv m \pmod N$ in all cases, includes ones which $m$ and $N$ are not relatively prime.

What is an issue is if someone notices that $\gcd(m, N) \neq 1$.  If that is the case (and $m \ne 0$), then $\gcd(m, N)$ is a nontrivial factor of $N$, that is, either $p$ and $q$, and so that rather leaks the factorization of $N$.

Now, the probability of guessing $m$ that is not relatively prime to $N$ is astronomically small for the sizes of $N$ we use in practice, and so we don't worry about it.

Comment: Addition: In Rivest, Shamir, and Adleman's work as of April 1977 ([references](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52528/555)), the proof required $\gcd(m,N)\neq1$. And, including in the [published paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf#page=6), $p$ and $q$ are large random primes but not explicitly distinct (nor explicitly independent). If we allow $p=q$ (modern expositions of RSA do not), $\gcd(m,N)\neq1$ is required for reversible encryption. That condition also ensures reversible encryption in some variants of RSA that have been investigated, including $N=p^2\cdot q$.

Comment: @fgrieu: as for the original proof of RSA, well, people have since created sharper proofs that hold in general.  As for nonsquare free varients of RSA, I consider them exactly that, varients, and not the original RSA.